# I want to show pdf document in lightbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am try to show pdf document in lightbox but when i click it open a pdf in other tab not in lightbox.
I am new at web development.

HTML:

```
<p><a class="iframe" href="http://contents.tacticalasia.com/download/511-Tactical-Catalog-2012.pdf">Zero</a></p>
```

jQUERY:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("a.iframe").fancybox({
'width': 640, // or whatever you want
 'height': 480, // or whatever you want
 'type': 'iframe'
 });
 });
```

Here is my link [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g36YD/7/)

Comment: If you are seeking for help, At least you should provide some code which is not working, and your expected output.

Comment: @NiravMadariya check the fiddel i want to open pdf in this box.

Comment: so what is the problem?

Comment: @GauravAggarwal pdf file is not open in lightbox

Comment: authentication is required...i checked opening the iframe link in other window then also authentication is required to see the pdf...do u have the creds?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add attribute `target` to `<a>` tag,
Then it will look like this :

```
<p><a class="iframe" href="http://contents.tacticalasia.com/download/511-Tactical-Catalog-2012.pdf" target="">Zero</a></p>
```

`target="blank"` will open it in another tab, and `target=""` will open it in current tab.

Comment: @Asad Ali, If this answer solves ur problem then accept this answer, So that others with the same problem can have solution.